# Subsolution of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $w(>0)\in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ satisfies the equation 
$$
-\Delta w\leq e^w\text{ in }\Omega.
$$
Let $v(>0)\in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ satisfies
the equation 
$$
-\Delta v=e^v\text{ in }\Omega.
$$
Then is it true that $w\leq v$ in $\Omega$?

I am trying to prove by observing that $w$ is a subsolution of the second equation, but unable to derive the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim seems to be wrong.

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Omega$ and we set $f = \chi_K$ (characteristic function of $K$) and $w_0 := (-\Delta)^{-1}(f) \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
Then, we should have $w_0 \ge c$ on $K$ for some $c > 0$. Now, we choose $\lambda > 0$ with $\lambda < e^{\lambda \, c}$. We set $w := \lambda \, w_0$. This yields
$$
-\Delta w = -\lambda \, \Delta w = \lambda \, f.
$$
On $K$, we have
$$
\lambda \, f = \lambda \le e^{\lambda \,c } \le e^{\lambda \, w_0} = e^{w}.$$
On $\Omega \setminus K$, we have
$$
\lambda \, f = 0 \le 1 \le e^{w}.$$

Hence, $w$ solves your equation, but with
$\lambda \to \infty$ (which is possible),
it
cannot satisfy $w \le v$ for a fixed $v$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Suppose $w$ is a given subsolution as above , then can one always get such $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap C^1(\Omega)$ such that $w\leq v$? Please help me.

Comment: This is a different question. I don't know.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.